# Configuring Python to use additional locations for site-packages

Tags: python, package

Is there a way to tell Python about additional `site-packages` locations without modifying existing scripts?

On my CentOS 5.5 server I have a Python 2.7 installation that is installed in `/opt/python2.7.2` and there is a `site-packages` folder at `/opt/python2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

The reason for this is that I didn't want to disturb the existing Python 2.4 install that shipped with the 5.5 distribution.

However a third party Python application also added a `site-packages` folder at: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and installed itself at that location.

This is partly my fault because I didn't tweak the `PREFIX` in the application's `Makefile` before installing, however there's not much I can do about it now.

I know that I can do this:

```
import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
```

However it would involve me tracking down every script and adding the above which is not ideal should there be updates in the future.

To get around this I created a symbolic link in `/opt/python2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to the location of this third party application:

```
ln -sf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theapp /opt/python2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theapp
```

This appears to work fine but I'm wondering if there's a better way?

Comment: Just curious how did your symlink approach treat changes to the target source that was being linked? Did it successfully pick them up?

Comment: @jxramos - This is so long ago I honestly don't remember. It was a one-off thing for an internal server running RhodeCode (a webby front end for Mercurial and Mercurial's server), it all seemed to work fine. I ended up fixing my mistake in the end (at least according to my comment under Shawn's accepted answer :) ).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the [Site-specific configuration hook](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html).

> "A path configuration file is a file whose name has the form `name.pth` and exists in one of the four directories mentioned above; its contents are additional items (one per line) to be added to `sys.path`."

In your case, you should be able to achieve what you want by simply dropping in a `.pth` file containing the path of the directory to include:

```
[root@home]$ echo "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/" > /opt/python2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usrlocal.pth
```

Comment: This works a treat, however I decided to bit the bullet and fix the deployment. But thanks anyway, useful to know for the future.

Comment: This adds the path to the *end* of the python path. What if you want your custom site-packages to come first? I've been experimenting with a sitecustomize.py file with some success, but there seem to be edge cases where simply manipulating the python path isn't enough.

Answer (score 8):

You could replace the python executable with a wrapper script which appends your added installpath to PYTHONPATH. But this is a kludge.

But I'd try to fix the installation of the add-on so that it properly goes into the site-packages dir.

Comment: Shawn's answer did the trick, but you're right as well in that fixing the install is actually better in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

To change the path of `site-packages` of Python:

**Step 1:** via **`PYTHONUSERBASE`** environment variable

*a. For Windows*

```
SET PYTHONUSERBASE=<custom-path>

For Example:
SET PYTHONUSERBASE=C:\\DEV\python_repo
```

**Step 2:** via **`--user`**

While installing module or package via `pip` use `--user` as show below:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip --user
```

***Note:***

1. Follow both the above step to get site-packages to custom location.