# Workaround read-only site-packages for cx_freeze

Tags: python, solaris, cx-freeze

I'm currently trying to make `cx_freeze` to work on a Solaris workstation I have to work with, in order to make an executable from a Python script I have. Problem is, I'm not administrator of this machine, and installation of `cx_freeze` requests write to site-packages, which is read-only for me.

So, obviously, I get this error:

```
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cx_Freeze
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cx_Freeze': Read-only file system
```

And if I try to run it anyway, it fails:

```
bash-3.00$ python /home/xxxx/cx_freeze-4.2.3/cxfreeze --target-dir cx_dist src/p_tool.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxxx/cx_freeze-4.2.3/cxfreeze", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/xxxx/cx_freeze-4.2.3/cx_Freeze/main.py", line 187, in main
    silent = options.silent)
  File "/home/xxxx/cx_freeze-4.2.3/cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 91, in __init__
    self._VerifyConfiguration()
  File "/home/xxxx/cx_freeze-4.2.3/cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 371, in _VerifyConfiguration
    self._GetInitScriptFileName()
  File "/home/xxxx/cx_freeze-4.2.3/cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 283, in _GetInitScriptFileName
    raise ConfigError("no initscript named %s", name)
cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no initscript named Console
```

Obviously, this is linked to the failed installation. So, here's my question:

**Without installation of `virtualenv`, could I avoid the writing to `site-packages`, and make `cx_freeze` to execute from my home folder?**

---

**EDIT** I had a look [at site.py documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html), and `PYTHONPATH` filling should be equivalent to use of `site-packages`. So my question is now more something like: what is the path to be added to `PYTHONPATH`, so that `cx_freeze` could be executed from any location?

---

Notes:

- I would like to avoid to deal with `virtualenv`, as I'm already struggling to understand the executable tools...
- I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901373/configuring-python-to-use-additional-locations-for-site-packages), but this still requires access to `site-packages` folder, plus it's not user-specific;
- I tried adding the following path to PYTHONPATH, but this does not work: `/home/xxxx/cx_freeze-4.2.3/build/lib.solaris-2.10-sun4v-2.6`;
- I'm also trying to use `PyInstaller` but have dependency problems (and the administrator is not really helping me).

Comment: not a python/virtualenv expert but virtualenv would be the solution...

Comment: Mmh, from what I read here: http://docs.python.org/library/site.html and in `site.py` code,  `site-packages` is similar to having `PYTHONPATH` updated: they both should result in `sys.path` to be appended with specified locations. Then it seems to be more a question of: what is `cx_freeze` trying to find exactly? [question updated]

Comment: The admins of my shared hosting set up an alternate location under my control for python packages and kindly explained the process to me, HIH:  Create a directory /home/xxxxx/data/python, which includes a bin and lib folder. NB this is the same as ~/data/python/; Create a .bash_profile that includes the new dirs in PATH and PYTHON_PATH; 
Create a .pydistutils.cfg that specifies to install new python modules into the new dirs; Download 'setuptools' (http://goo.gl/ar2Wv) and install (python setup.py install); 
When working with apps, make sure PYTHON_PATH is set to reference your new folders.

Comment: Good to know, but now, I've got access problems to the workstation... I'll try this as soon as I can. As I should be the only one to use this mechanism, this could work.

Comment: @MichaelJW Ok this works great now! I'd be happy to accept the answer you would write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works like a charm for me :

```
$ python setup.py install --home=$HOME
```

Run in the source directory of cx_freeze found [on the Sourceforge download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cx-freeze/files/4.2.3/cx_Freeze-4.2.3.tar.gz/download%20here).