# How to add NUKE API to Visual Studio code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, nuke

I'm new to Python scripting in NUKE. I'm using VS code as my IDE.
Question: is there any way to add a NUKE API to VS code intelsense?

*Nuke is a software made by foundry(https://www.foundry.com/products/nuke-family/nuke) used in film post productions. nuke itself has an built in IDE but it's very basic.

Comment: What is Nuke? You will need to be more specific about what you're after as it isn't clear if this is something you're trying to install, some app that uses Python for scripting, etc.

Comment: Nuke is one of the core software in Visual effect Industry which has its own API to write tools..etc. It also has its own editor to write python code. I am trying to write codes for Nuke in Vs code instead but of course Nuke API is not known for Vs code. ex: in nuke if you type nuke.     it will shows all the function after the dot...I am trying to have that in VS code.

Comment: Do you know where the library code for the SDK is kept? Basically it the intellisense engines don't know where the code lives it can't look at it to figure out how to autocomplete for it.

Comment: @I'm not familiar with SDK. Basically you are saying that nuke must SDK library? Kept in a specific path(where its download). How I can find out if nuke has SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foundry offer support on using Nuke as a Python module here : https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/content/comp_environment/script_editor/nuke_python_module.html

Though personally, I would recommend installing a better Python Script Editor into the Nuke UI and working inside of Nuke with that - lots of what you do with Nuke's API is dependent on selecting Nodes or visually confirming your code is working as intended. I feel this is an important aspect of learning Nuke's python API.

I use this : https://github.com/plasmax/PythonEditor

Since it gives you tabs and is generally much nicer to use than Nuke's vanilla script editor. Later on once you've got a handle on this and want to start running Nuke batch scripts via the terminal is more the time when using an external IDE makes more sense. Good luck!

Comment: I found the first link on my search but had no Idea what they mean by usrlocal.pth

Comment: @bigly - a .pth file is a path configuration file. Adding one into the python site-packages allows you to add other directories python can use for site-packages.

Check out this question/answer for more information : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901373/configuring-python-to-use-additional-locations-for-site-packages

You'll note the top answer has a direct reference to this usrlocal.pth