# Python Pip Local Download

Tags: python, pip

So I am looking to download Flask (and all other dependencies) locally for my project. I do this using the following code:

```
pip install -t lib Flask
```

This works and executes correctly. The result of this is saved in the `lib` directory. However, when trying to import Flask from `lib.Flask`, this error comes up:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jinja2'
```

I understand that Flask depends on this library, but it was installed with the above command along with Flask. In other words, `jinja2` is in the `lib` directory.

Why am I getting this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: so did you fix your issue, or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you import a module in python, the first thing python does is look for it in your immediate directory, then if its not found there it searches for it in the python's global lib install path, then if its not found there either it throws an error

there is also this thing called relative and global import in python, im pretty sure that `Flask` uses both(relative for itself inside the module, and global for external dependencies)

for your locally stored `Flask` to work you either need to make python think it's part of it's global module index or go into `Flask` and fix all global imports to relative for its external dependencies by hand

EDIT:

for example you have a lib folder:

```
lib/
  foo/   # module
  bar/   # module
  spam/  # module
```

the laziest way to make python see them as part of its global(user/system wide) module index is to add each one of them to `PATH`

in case of this example your additions to `PATH` would look like this:

```
full/path/to/lib/foo
```

to get python to see `foo` as a module from this `lib` folder

if you want python to recognize `bar` and `spam` too, you need to add them both in the same manner

EDIT2: the lazy way part 2

lets say you have some modules with dependencies and all of them are in some folder:

```
lib/
  lol/   # module, its just here
  foo/   # module, bar needs this
  bar/   # module, spam needs this
  spam/  # module, you only need this
```

again the laziest way to get python to see `lib` as part for it's global(user/system wide) module index is to add the `lib` folder to `PATH`

and you can do so from python itself:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/full/path/to/your/lib')
>>> import spam # now this will work, any other module from lib/ will work too
```

Comment: How would I make python think it's part of it's global module index?

Comment: another way to add modules to python's global(user/system wide) module index is to use [Site-specific configuration hook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html)

Comment: also this might straight up have a solution for you
[Configuring Python to use additional locations for site-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7901603/10190971)

Comment: So if i do not have access to the PATH, because I am running this on a serverless instance, should I use the site-packages method?

Comment: i think you can modify PATH using `sys.path` in python, changes wont be permanent, but it will work(i tested this on a serverless windows machine, linux will work too)

Comment: So Flask is only one of my modules. I have downloaded all necessary modules into a local "lib" folder in my project's directory. Is there a way I can just set that folder as the "dependency folder" globally?

Answer (score 0):

`Flask` depends on the `jinja2` module, installing it with :

```
python -m pip install jinja2
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install jinja2
```

depending on the python version will solve the issue for you.