# Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named Rich

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use rich module to draw table in python3.9 in Linux.
However, I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/audit.py", line 12, in <module>
    fom rich.table import Table
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rich'
```

I have both python 2.7 and 3.9 installed.
Command I run: python3.9 /opt/audit.py

```
I have verified I have rich installed. 
python3.9 -m pip list
Package        Version
-------------- -------
ansitable      0.9.7
colored        2.2.2
markdown-it-py 3.0.0
mdurl          0.1.2
pip            22.0.4
Pygments       2.15.1
rich           13.4.2
setuptools     58.1.0

python3.9 -m pip install rich --upgrade
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: rich in /disk2/users/python3.9/site-packages (13.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown-it-py>=2.2.0 in /disk2/users/python3.9/site-packages (from rich) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in /disk2/users/python3.9/site-packages (from rich) (2.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: mdurl~=0.1 in /disk2/users/python3.9/site-packages (from markdown-it-py>=2.2.0->rich) (0.1.2)
```

This is the start of the file and it fails on line 12:

```
import cx_Oracle
import configparser
import json
import os
import requests
import smtplib

from rich.table import Table
from email.message import EmailMessage
from pathlib import Path
```

Comment: A side comment: upgrade cx_Oracle to the latest version, which is now called python-oracledb see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Comment: can you give an example script that fails? What Linux flavor/variant are you running as well?

Comment: Did you try installing with `pip3`? Most likely your `rich` library is installed in your python 2.7, since you installing it with `pip`. However, since you are executing the script from python 3.9, it's not getting the `rich` library.

Comment: @Raktim I am running python3.9 -m pip list and it display rich, so that means rich is installed for python3.9 pip right?

Comment: Try running `from pip import _internal;
_internal.main(['list']); from rich.table import Table` from the REPL.

Comment: _it fails on line 12_ That code sample is only 10 lines long...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that package has been installed correctly, it is possible that **python3** is not loading packages installed on that path due to some misconfiguration.

You can start troubleshooting by checking where the module was installed by pip:

```
$ python3 -m pip show rich

Name: rich
Version: 13.4.2
Summary: Render rich text, tables, progress bars, syntax highlighting, markdown and more to the terminal
Home-page: https://github.com/Textualize/rich
Author: Will McGugan
Author-email: willmcgugan@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: markdown-it-py, pygments
Required-by:
```

If the `Location` path is also present in the `sys.path` list below, it means that this path is part of the *global* site-packages directories and python should be able to find the module when the interpreter runs:

```
$ python3 -m site

sys.path = [
    '/Users/Admin/workspace',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python311.zip',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/Admin/Library/Python/3.11' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/Users/Admin/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

As you can see in this example, the `Location` path is the last entry on `sys.path`. However, if it's not in there, there's a chance it might be listed by the *user* site-package directories:

```
$ python3 -m site --user-site
```

If the `Location` path is not present in either of these site-packages, then [you can try to add that path to one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7901373/176769). But at this point I would seriously question the integrity of your python installation.

Comment: When I ran python3.9 -m pip show rich: Location: /disk2/users/sh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages. When I ran python3.9 -m site: sys.path = [
    '/disk2/users/do',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.9',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
    '/disk2/users/sh/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
]. So python3.9 should be able to see rich module. In the end, I ran print(sys.module) to see that other modules were in /opt/aduit/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ so i manually downloaded rich and put it there and it worked.