# In Python3.11.4, why is pip install -e failing to build this package?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

In Python 3.11.4, in MacOS 13.4.1, I am installing a package of mine with  pip3 install -e and seeing the following errors.    pip appears to be failing to import Numpy in the environment used for the build.

Numpy is installed; I can import Numpy normally in interactive Python sessions.

I completely uninstalled and reinstalled Py3.11 and numpy, including the entire site-package directory, with no change.

I have built this package on other machines with Python 3.11.1 and the same setup.py and _*init*_.py files.  I don't understand what is different on this particular system, and if I need to install or activate Numpy for the pip environment I can't find how to do that.

```
tlh:prog/python % pip3 install -e gemvms
Obtaining file:///Users/tlh/prog/python/gemvms
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [30 lines of output]
      /Users/tlh/prog/python/gemvms/gemvms/__init__.py:15: UserWarning: warn test
        warn("warn test")
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 132, in get_requires_for_build_editable
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/t9/tmj9gs9146jcqc1p0lh2c4bc000314/T/pip-build-env-tmurvx_a/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 450, in get_requires_for_build_editable
          return self.get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/t9/tmj9gs9146jcqc1p0lh2c4bc000314/T/pip-build-env-tmurvx_a/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/t9/tmj9gs9146jcqc1p0lh2c4bc000314/T/pip-build-env-tmurvx_a/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/t9/tmj9gs9146jcqc1p0lh2c4bc000314/T/pip-build-env-tmurvx_a/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 488, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/t9/tmj9gs9146jcqc1p0lh2c4bc000314/T/pip-build-env-tmurvx_a/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
        File "/Users/tlh/prog/python/gemvms/gemvms/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
          from .data    import VMSData
        File "/Users/tlh/prog/python/gemvms/gemvms/data.py", line 55, in <module>
          import numpy as np
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: You can try checking if numpy is installed in the expected location. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76684068/7886059

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  'pip show numpy' shows Numpy in the expected location /Library/Frameworks/...site-packages, and this directory is present in sys.path.   I can also import Numpy just fine in normal use, so I don't see any basic problem with my python or Numpy installation.

Comment: After comparing the verbose messages from "pip3 install -v -e gemvms" between this new installation and an existing installation where it worked, I realized that I had not installed "wheel" on the new machine.   After installing  "wheel", the "install -e" found all the dependent packages and completed successfully.  I don't think the error messages or the documentation I read about "pip3 install -e" mention that "wheel" is required.